# Postgres service restart in a Master - Replica

Tags: postgresql, replication, shutdown

Postgres 10 database running on a Centos RHEL 7. This Database is a Master and it has 1 stand_by replica acting as a mirror. Well my intention was to change the `wal_level` in the configuration from `replica` to `logical`, so I did, I changed it in the `postgresql.conf` and tried to restart the service as the instructions in the `postgresql.conf` said.

`systemctl restart postgresql-10.service` didn't worked, when I execute `systemctl status postgresql-10.service` this is shown:

```
● postgresql-10.service - PostgreSQL 10 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-10.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar 2018-10-30 10:40:40 GMT; 12min ago
     Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/
  Process: 19359 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 19353 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgresql-10-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19359 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

oct 30 10:40:40 server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server...
oct 30 10:40:40 server postmaster[19359]: 2018-10-30 10:40:40.431 GMT [19359] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
oct 30 10:40:40 server postmaster[19359]: 2018-10-30 10:40:40.431 GMT [19359] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 8545) running in data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/10/data"?
oct 30 10:40:40 server systemd[1]: postgresql-10.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 30 10:40:40 server systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 10 database server.
oct 30 10:40:40 server systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-10.service entered failed state.
oct 30 10:40:40 server systemd[1]: postgresql-10.service failed
```

Ok, now the Centos service interface shows that the service has failed, due to some `postmaster.pid` lock file that the postmaster process uses, that's true, the file exists and the postmaster process is still running, the database cluster is still accessible.

I read in the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/server-shutdown.html) that the Smart Shutdown mode may be waiting for some sessions in the pg_stat_activity to finish.

What can I do to safely restart the cluster with the new `wal_level` setting and sync the status of the postmaster process and the `postgresql-10` service